# How do I generate all new records for a given model randomly using pre-defined options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like one of my models, Stones, to be generated at random using pre-defined options I've stored in a set of arrays and hashes. Instead of Create using params from the URL, I'd like new Stones to always be defined using this random generation process. I don't need any user input at all, except that each stone belongs to a given player.

I'm still new to rails; where should I put all this code? I know enough to be able to define the arrays and hashes and randomly select from them when I need to, but I'm not sure where and how to replace the part of the code that draws params from URLs and fills in a new record before it is saved. I know controllers are supposed to be skinny, so do I do this in the model?

Apologies if this is a duplicate. I searched extensively and couldn't find an applicable solution.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you considered using [after_initialize](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find)?

Comment: @jvillian yes, but I was only able to find examples to respond to user input, such as "if a certain field is empty, replace it with a default value." But I don't ever want to take *any* input from the user. Should I just act as if it's possible to receive user input (but never allow it at the view level) and then over-write the unused user input using after_initialize?

Comment: If you don't have input fields in the view (or wherever/however you're instantiating a new record or loading an existing record), then you don't have to 'over-write' anything. Just check if the field value is `nil` and then assign random attributes if it is.

Comment: Ok! I'll try that. I just wasn't sure if that was somehow bad form, essentially pretending like there might be user input when there never will be any. Thank you!

Comment: It's easy.If you want to have this actions automatically you have to generate a rails rake task or rails job .Then define your data if it is not considerably much (if it is you'd better to store it in db or an individual file). Then put your job in queue to do it regularly .

Comment: for randomly choosing you can use "sample" method which is for arrays => [1,2,3,4].sample  this gives you one of these randomly !

Comment: @ATF thank you! I actually need to do this "on command" rather than regularly, so I don't think I need to queue it. The sample method is going to be my first attempt, thanks!

Comment: So you probably need a rake task ! By the way you also can use the seed.rb in db folder to predefined some data and run it on command !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a service for this. Something like:

```
# app/services/stone_creator.rb
class RandomStoneCreator
  RANDOM_FOOS = ['bar', 'baz', 'bat']

  def self.call(user)
    Stone.create!({
      foo: RANDOM_FOOS.sample,
      user: user
    })
  end
end
```

And then anywhere that you need a new random stone you can call it like:

```
random_stone = RandomStoneCreator.call(current_user)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Once I generate random_stone, would I still use after_initialize and go column by column, like self.column = random_stone.column?

Comment: No. In this scenario the `RandomStoneCreator` class would house all of the random selection code. The `foo` attribute is an example of how you'd set an attribute to a random value.